# Ninject Conditional injection problems

Tags: ninject

I have the following bindings declared

```
Bind<IDataSource>().To<DataSourceOne>();

Bind<ISettings>().To<DataSourceSettings>
    .WhenInjectedInto<DataSourceOne>();
Bind<ISettings>().To<Settings>();
```

now I call

```
Kernel.Get<IDataSourc>();
```

Ninject correctly injects a DataSourceSettings, but I need to pass a constructor argument to Settings and DataSourceSettings based on data from a config file. so I've changed the IDataSouce binding as follows

```
Kernel.Bind<IDataSource>().To<DataSourceOne>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("settings", Kernel.Get<ISettings>( 
        new ConstructorArgument("data", objectContainingConfigFileData)
    )
);
```

in that case Ninject injects Settings class instead of DataSourceSettings class. I assume the problem is that the ISettings is getting resolved before it is injected into the DataSourceSettings class so Ninject does not use the binding I intended it to. Is there a way to get around this. I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: It seems to me that you're having some ambiguity in your design. `ISettings` is ambiguous. Instead of giving yourself a hard time with conditional injection, why not define two separate interfaces, since `DataSourceOne` clearly expects something different than the rest of the system does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you define the constructor argument for the ISettings binding and not for the DataSource binding. Assuming you already know the object with the config file data in the module. Otherwise maybe a factory would be more appropriate.

```
kernel.Bind<IDataSource>().To<DataSourceOne>();
kernel.Bind<ISettings>().To<DataSourceSettings>()
   .WhenInjectedInto<DataSourceOne>()
   .WithConstructorArgument("data", objectContainingConfigFileData);

kernel.Bind<ISettings>().To<Settings>();
```